# How to access Multi-level repo in aws codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have the following repo structure in AWS code commit.
I have MainRepo folder and inside it has 2 sub-folder inside which respective solution and `buildspec.yml` file present.

I am trying to build proj1.sln using aws codebuild service.

In Source section of aws codebuild, it allows to select `MainRepo` only.

How can i select sub-folder `Repo1` in aws codebuild?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `CodeCommit` Repository first and create the `CodeBuild` Project from there.

You can follow the steps as below :

1. Create a new `CodeCommit` Repository and copy the repository URL from the `CodeCommit` console.
2. Clone the `CodeCommit` Repository from inside your `<MainRepo>` directory in the local computer (here I am guessing you have the `MainRepo` directory in your local machine, if not then you can clone it to your local machine)
3. You will have a new repo directory (eg. `<Repo3>`) on your local system inside `<MainRepo>` directory.
4. Copy the .git folder from `<Repo3\.git>` to `<Repo1\.git>` and you can `git push` your files from `<Repo1>` to the `CodeCommit` Repository.
5. Then you can build your Artifacts/CodeBuild Projects from the newly created `CodeCommit` Repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't want to change the directory structure. There should be another way to access subfolder in codebuild.

Comment: @Nishant you don't have to change the directory structure, you can remove the Repo3 directory once you copy the .git folder or you can even create the Repo3 folder outside of your MainRepo folder (on your local machine) and remove it later.